# Mule ESB - Configure Multiple Components in same Flow

Tags: java, spring, mule, esb

I am getting an error message when trying to add a Spring component to a Mule Flow.  This should be a common user-case, but I wasn't able to find the right documentation or examples.  Thanks in advance.

The follow was the original configuration and works fine:

```
<flow name="ApplicationEndpoint">
    <inbound-endpoint address="server:port/JSONAPI/"/>
    <jersey:resources>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="myJerseyService"/>     
        </component>            
    </jersey:resources>

    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <flow-ref name="ErrorHandling" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>         
</flow>
```

I simply want to add a new component to do some post-processing.  When I try this, it doesn't work:

```
<flow name="ApplicationEndpoint">
    <inbound-endpoint address="server:port/JSONAPI/"/>
    <jersey:resources>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="myJerseyService"/>     
        </component>            
    </jersey:resources>
    <component>
      <spring-object bean="postProcessor"/>
    <component>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <flow-ref name="ErrorHandling" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>         
</flow>
```

Where "postProcessor" maps elsewhere in the config as a spring bean.

The error message I get is:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'component'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-lifecycle-adapter-factory, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":binding}' is expected.

Comment: I tried your configuration and landed with The endpoint "server:port/JSONAPI/" is malformed and cannot be parsed., can you post entire XML and full stacktrace of your error please.

Answer (score 1):

The above error clearly shows that the tag `<component>` is not closed..

for example, it should be in following format :-

```
 <component>
    <spring-object bean="postProcessor"/>
 </component>
```

where you need to end the tag like the following :- `</component>`

One more thing ... I tried to run your code, but due to `server:port/JSONAPI/` configured in your `inbound-endpoint` address it gives a error saying the xml is malformed

So I modified your code as following and it ran successfully :-

```
<flow name="ApplicationEndpoint">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8189/JSONAPI"/>
    <jersey:resources>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="myJerseyService"/>     
        </component>            
    </jersey:resources>
    <component>
      <spring-object bean="postProcessor"/>
    </component>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <flow-ref name="ErrorHandling" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>         
</flow>
```

So, you can now use it and modify as per your requirement

Comment: Thank-you so much.  I can't believe I didn't see that.